# How to make template for promise function with Sql queries in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, asynchronous

I have few functions which does the same for different objects. For example:

```
    const returnMiscArray = () => {
    var i = 0;
    var id = 0;
    misc = _util.toNull(misc);

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        while (Number(order.id[id]) != Number(orderid)) id++;
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM misc WHERE uniqid = ?`, [order.uniqid[id]], function(error, results) {
            while (i < results.length) {
                misc.uniqid[i] = results[i].uniqid;
                misc.id[i] = results[i].id;
                misc.count[i] = results[i].count;
                misc.cost[i] = results[i].cost;
                misc.product[i] = results[i].product;
                misc.fcost[i] = results[i].fcost;
                i++;
            }
            resolve(misc);
        });
    });
    return (promise);
}
```

and

```
const returnPositionsArray = () => {
    var i = 0;
    var id = 0;
    positions = _util.toNull(positions);

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        while (Number(order.id[id]) != Number(orderid)) id++;
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM positions WHERE uniqid = ?`, [order.uniqid[id]], function(error, results) {
            while (i < results.length) {
                positions.uniqid[i] = results[i].uniqid;
                positions.id[i] = results[i].id;
                positions.length[i] = results[i].len;
                positions.sqr[i] = results[i].sqr;
                positions.cost[i] = results[i].cost;
                positions.count[i] = results[i].count;
                i++;
            }
            resolve(positions);
        });
    });

    return (promise);
}
```

I want to make one function which takes object as argument, changes it and returns promise.
thinking of something like that:

```
const returnArray = (object, cur_order, id) => {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    object = _util.toNull(object);
    var objstr = somevalue;  /* CONVERT PASSED OBJECT VARIABLE NAME TO STRING */
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        while (Number(cur_order.id[j] != Number(id))) j++;
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ` + objstr + ` WHERE uniqid = ?`, [cur_order.uniqid[j]], function(error, results) {
            while (i < results.length) {
                /*
                     
                    SOMETHING HERE

                */
            }
            resolve(object);
        });
        return (promise);
    });
}
```

but I have no idea how can i make it work. I know we can go through object parameters using keys, but how can I do the same for sql results?

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: sql result is just a simple Array of objects, so just use loop over object's own keys

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you have two functions which handle specific tables. You're already seeing that this is an opportunity to avoid repetition by using abstraction.  The question is: *what do we abstract?*

Look at the two functions and see what is different between the two.  Based on what you've written here, what you need to pass in is a table name and a callback that takes a result and it's index `i`.

But I don't love the code that you've written for a bunch of reasons.

- It would probably be better to fetch multiple ids in one SQL call using `IN` with an array.
- Your query callback needs to reject the Promise in the case of an error.
- You’re resolving a promise from a loop?
- I genuinely don't understand what you are doing with `misc.uniqid[i]...` Why not just return the results, or a mapped version of them?
- Where are these variables `order.id` and `orderid` in the first two functions coming from?  Can you write the function such that it gets everything it needs from its arguments?